# Sending various parameteres to PHP function, they're not catched in order

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP (7), and I'm having issues understanding how to pass parameters to PHP functions, from the first php script, I make a call to the following function:

```
public static function UpdateDatos($UserPassword, $idUser, $OldUserPassword)
{
    if (self::ObtenerDatosPorId($idUser)) {
        try {
            $consultar = "UPDATE Usuarios SET UserPassword = ? WHERE idUser = ? AND UserPassword = ?";
            $resultado = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consultar);
            return $resultado->execute(array($UserPassword, $idUser, $OldUserPassword));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

when I call this method like this, while debugging, I can see that datos[] have the following values:

```
$datos["UserPassword"]    = "newPassword"
$datos["idUser"]          = "15"
$datos["OldUserPassword"] = "OldPassword"
```

Here everything is ok, but when I call the function with these values...

```
$datos = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$respuesta = Registro::UpdateDatos( $datos["UserPassword"], $datos["idUser"], $datos["OldUserPassword"]);
```

Back in the function declaration, I see the arguments have been mapped wrongly, like this;

```
$datos["UserPassword"]    = "15" 
$datos["idUser"]          = "OldPassword"
$datos["OldUserPassword"] = "newPassword"
```

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening? I know they're anonymus variables, but aren't they supposed to be received in the same order I sent them?.

Thank you in advance and sorry if this has already been asked, couldn't find any answer but turning it into an array,

Comment: I don't see any kind of reference to `$datos` in your function. My best guess is you have them mislabeled in whatever is coming from your "php://input"

Comment: That is most likely a problem with the JSON data you are receiving from the outside here.

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem, I was sending the JSON wrongly via POSTMAN...

Comment: Flagging as _This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a **simple typographical error**_